# Metal 'texture' not found

Tags: ios, core-image, metal

With every Implementation of Metal based ImageView I'm facing the same problem

```
let targetTexture = currentDrawable?.texture else{ return }
```

> Value of type 'MTLDrawable' has no member 'texture'

Seems like apple has changed some metal api

here is the full function I'm tryong to use:

```
func renderImage()
{
    guard let
        image = image,
        let targetTexture = currentDrawable?.texture else{return}

    let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()

    let bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: drawableSize)

    let originX = image.extent.origin.x
    let originY = image.extent.origin.y

    let scaleX = drawableSize.width / image.extent.width
    let scaleY = drawableSize.height / image.extent.height
    let scale = min(scaleX, scaleY)

    let scaledImage = image
        .applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -originX, y: -originY))
        .applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale))

    ciContext.render(scaledImage,
                     to: targetTexture,
                     commandBuffer: commandBuffer,
                     bounds: bounds,
                     colorSpace: colorSpace)

    commandBuffer.present(currentDrawable!)

    commandBuffer.commit()
}
```

Comment: Show the declaration and assignment of your `currentDrawable` variable. According to the error, it's of type `MTLDrawable` which does not, in fact, have a `texture` property. I imagine you were thinking of `CAMetalDrawable`, which does.

Comment: @KenThomases but in every implementation Metal kit view was done in this way, and there no way to invoke CAMetalDrawable from MTLDrawable

Comment: Are you implementing a subclass of `MTKView`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same problem after performing a system and xcode update. Turns out during the update process, xcode switched the build target to the simulator. Once I switched the target back to the device it all compiled again.

Comment: It worked, thank you. But why It was made so freaking stupid it's a question for Apple

Answer (score 0):

Metal doesn't work for simulators, but if you just want the build to pass and focus in other areas of your app you can try to do something similar to this:
For those who still want to run on simulators, there's a workaround for at least getting it running and compile (no Metal functionality though)

https://navoshta.com/metal-camera-bonus-running-simulator/